# what is the repo in order to install jar file on redhat 7

Tags: rhel, yum, java, repository

what is the repo ( under /etc/yum.repo.d ) , in order to install jar command ?

```
yum install jar
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-    manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can    use subscription-manager to register.
     HighAvailability                                                                                 | 4.1 kB  00:00:00
   ResilientStorage                                                                                | 4.1 kB  00:00:00
 local                                                                                           | 4.1 kB  00:00:00
 No package jar available.
 Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: Doesn't look like any of your configure yum repos contain the jar RPM or the jar command is part of a RPM not called 'jar'.  Try executing 'sudo yum provides '*/jar'.

Comment: That would probably be `java-1.8.0-openjdk` in base.

Comment: how to download it?

Comment: I have already java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version ( but not jar command )

Answer (score 1):

The command `java -jar file.jar`
should do the trick. The man page on java should help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` package.